# como puedo completar estos metodos?

Tags: java

hola chicos soy novato en el mundo de la programacion y se me da algo duro entender ciertas cosas en un codigo ya realizado en clase me han pedido que complete esto dos metodos ambos en un ArrayList, pero no se que metodos usar aclaro que no dejan usar el try catch que he visto que es una opcion. cualquier ayuda lo agradeceria bastante saludos!

1. eliminar un libro dado su ISBN
2. comprobar si existe un libro dado su ISBN

Comment: Recuerda realizar tus preguntas en el sitio en base a [ask], agrega lo que has tratado modifica tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: @Elenasys hola gracias por la sugerencia, lo he modificado.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la pregunta no demuestra ninguna investigación ni esfuerzo.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

La manera "moderna" de hacer esas operaciones es con el uso de `lambdas`:

```
public void borrarLibro(String isbn, List<Libro> libros){
    libros.removeIf(libro->isbn.equals(libro.getIsbn());
}
```

```
public void existeLibro(String isbn, List<Libro> libros){
    return libros.stream().anyMatch(libro->isbn.equals(libro.getIsbn());
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! saludos